# How to run programs with ld-linux.so?

Tags: linux, libraries, dynamic-linking, ld, dynamic-loading

> **The dynamic linker can be run** either indirectly by running some dynamically linked program or shared object (in which case no command-line options to the dynamic linker can be passed and, in the ELF case, the dynamic linker which is stored in the .interp section of the program is executed) or **directly by running:**
>
> **/lib/ld-linux.so.* [OPTIONS] [PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS]]**

https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/man-pages/ld.so.8.en

Similar info can be found in [Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html).

But when I try,

```
$ LD_DEBUG=libs /usr/lib/ld-linux.so.2 ls
     23325: find library=ls [0]; searching
     23325:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     23325: 
ls: error while loading shared libraries: ls: cannot open shared object file

$ LD_DEBUG=libs ls
     23503: find library=libcap.so.2 [0]; searching
     23503:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     23503:   trying file=/usr/lib/libcap.so.2
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use `ld-linux.so` directly to run a program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using full path for `ls`:

```
[ctor@dom0 tst]$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ls
afile

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ls
ls: error while loading shared libraries: ls: cannot open shared object file

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 anyinexistentcommandhere
anyinexistentcommandhere: error while loading shared libraries: anyinexistentcommandhere: cannot open shared object file

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ ldd ls
ldd: ./ls: No such file or directory

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ ldd `type -P ls`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd636c000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000074b858cc3000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x000074b858abe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000074b8586f8000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x000074b858486000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000074b858282000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000074b85910a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000074b858064000)

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ LD_DEBUG=libs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ls
      6380: find library=ls [0]; searching
      6380:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6380: 
ls: error while loading shared libraries: ls: cannot open shared object file

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ LD_DEBUG=libs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 inexistentcommand
      6415: find library=inexistentcommand [0]; searching
      6415:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6415: 
inexistentcommand: error while loading shared libraries: inexistentcommand: cannot open shared object file

[ctor@dom0 tst]$ LD_DEBUG=libs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/bin/ls
      6342: find library=libselinux.so.1 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libselinux.so.1
      6342: 
      6342: find library=libcap.so.2 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libcap.so.2
      6342: 
      6342: find library=libc.so.6 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libc.so.6
      6342: 
      6342: find library=libpcre.so.1 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libpcre.so.1
      6342: 
      6342: find library=libdl.so.2 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libdl.so.2
      6342: 
      6342: find library=libpthread.so.0 [0]; searching
      6342:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      6342:   trying file=/lib64/libpthread.so.0
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libpthread.so.0
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libc.so.6
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libdl.so.2
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libpcre.so.1
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libcap.so.2
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: calling init: /lib64/libselinux.so.1
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: initialize program: /usr/bin/ls
      6342: 
      6342: 
      6342: transferring control: /usr/bin/ls
      6342: 
afile
```

Comment: That’s exactly it, you need to specify the path if the binary isn’t in the current directory. Note that `/usr/bin/ls` will only work on distros which have merged `/` and `/usr`; `/bin/ls` should work everywhere.